# Test class shows Unexpected Token 'By' error

Tags: unit-test

How to pass the value for following test class

```
public static Result[] lookup(String searchString, String sObjectAPIName, String whereClause, String whereClauseType , String whereClauseValue, String displayField )
{
    System.debug('search string = ' + searchString);

    // Sanitze the input
    String sanitizedSearchString = String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchString);
    String sanitizedSObjectAPIName = String.escapeSingleQuotes(sObjectAPIName);
    String sanitizeWhereClause = '';
    String sanitizedDisplayField = '';

    List<String> listDisplayField = new List<String>();


    //
    if(whereClause != ''){

        if(whereClauseValue != ''){

            String[] listWhereClause = whereClause.split(',');
            String[] listWhereClauseType = whereClauseType.split(',');
            String[] listWhereClauseValue = whereClauseValue.split(',');


            sanitizeWhereClause = ' WHERE ' + buildWhereClause(listWhereClause,listWhereClauseType,listWhereClauseValue);    
        }

    }
    if(displayField != ''){
        sanitizedDisplayField = String.escapeSingleQuotes(displayField);
        listDisplayField = sanitizedDisplayField.split(',');
        sanitizedDisplayField = ', ' + sanitizedDisplayField;

    }


    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

    // Build our SOSL query
    String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + sanitizedSearchString + '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ' + sanitizedSObjectAPIName + ' (id,name '+ sanitizedDisplayField + sanitizeWhereClause +' ORDER BY Name) Limit 50'; 

    system.debug('SEARCH QUERY : ' + searchQuery);

    // Execute the Query
    List<List<SObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);

    // Create a list of matches to return
    for (SObject so : searchList[0])
    {

        //results.add(new Result((String)so.get('Name') + buildDisplayField(so,listDisplayField), so.Id));
        results.add(new Result((String)so.get('Name') + buildDisplayField(so,listDisplayField), so.Id, so));
    }

    System.debug('RESULT ' + results);
    return results;
}
```

---

Test class:

```
 public static testmethod void  LookupSObjectController(){
    List<String> listDisplayField=new List<String>();
    listDisplayField.add('s');
    listDisplayField.add('m');
    sObject sobj1 = new Account(Name='Trailhead');
     LookupSObjectController.lookup('SearchString','sobj1','select id,name from account','Where caluse','whereClauseValue','displayField');
}
```

In My case this Query is Building:

```
 FIND 'SearchString*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING sobj1 (id,name , displayField WHERE  ORDER BY Name) Limit 50
```

Test class gives following error:

```
    Unexpected token 'By'
```

After trying this code:

```
 LookupSObjectController.lookup('SearchString','sobj1__C','','','','');
```

I got this error:

```
System.QueryException: sObject type 'sobj1__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Please help me on these test class

Comment: Did you try removing `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: i have tried@Frodo. but its failing!!!!

Comment: This query `FIND {ab*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (id, name ORDER BY Name) Limit 50` working fine for me. Braces `{}` are only applied when you query on developer console.  So i think after removing `Where` it should work in your case.

Comment: I have tried above code,it shows error

Comment: i have tried below line of code.    LookupSObjectController.lookup('','Office__c','','','',''); it works!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In My case this Query is Building:
>
> `FIND 'SearchString*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING sobj1 (id,name ,
>   displayField WHERE  ORDER BY Name) Limit 50`

notice that you have a **WHERE** key word with no clause right after.